# SQL CE 3.5 - Select field from another table

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5, sql-server-ce

I'm working with databases for the first time (SQL CE 3.5) and I'm not certain how I define a relationship between tables where later ( I think) I'll have to use a join to select some value for one field from another table.

```
_________       __________    __________
MY TABLE|      | TABLE A |   | TABLE B |
---------      |---------|   |---------|
OrderID |      | a_Text  |   | b_Text  |   
---------      |---------|   |---------| 
a_Text  |
---------
b_Text  |
---------
```

When it is all implemented when I define a value for a_Text in [MY TABLE] I only want to be able to set a value for a_Text as defined in [Table A] (and again for b_Text).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want here is a [Foreign Key Constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175464%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) on your `a_Text` field which enforces a link between `MY_TABLE`/`TABLE_A` for that particular field value.

This is a *database* relationship and as such should be defined at database-level and if required, at model-level. Most modern day ORM technologies e.g. EntityFramework/NHibernate, do a pretty good job at representing the same relationships at model-level, or at least make it very trivial to do so - EF will do it automatically if you create a context via a database directly.

It's pretty simple to create a relationship using SQLCE through the VS Designer - [Walkthrough: Creating a SQL Server Compact Database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/vstudio/bb546200%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) gives an example of adding a relationship between two tables.

---

Based on your requirements I wouldn't recommend having your value field (`a_Text`) in `TABLE A` as the PK. One of the biggest concerns is if you update the key you need to cascade that change throughout the other referencing tables. It's much more flexible to introduce a [surrogate key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key) and make your `a_Text` field a [unique key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_key) itself.

```
  My Table      Table A    Table B
  --------      -------    -------
  OrderID       a_ID       a_ID
  a_ID          a_Text     a_Text
  b_ID
```

Comment: Whilst this is certainly a model of the relationship I wish to establish I'm yet to find an example where a_Text is not a number type. I want to be able to use nvarchar(12).

Comment: @SimonJohnson it's definitely possible to use a foreign key constraint with a text-type value (`GUID`s are essentially just large strings and they work just fine).

Comment: I tried this (setting the a_Text field to be a PK in [TABLE A]) and it kept failing until I restarted Visual Studio (2008), thanks for the help :)

Comment: @SimonJohnson no worries, yeah the VS designer can be quite buggy for SQLCE, it's also quite limited so you might be better off using direct SQL instead. Just a note on what your doing though, in terms of performance I would definitely not recommend using a text field as a PK in a database table. I would recommend using a surrogate key (e.g. auto-increment) and have your `a_Text` as a unique key on the table.

Comment: Its got to be a string value. So in this example Table A may contain three entries, Apple, Orange and Grape. When I create a record on My_Table I only want to be able to select a value from the records that exist on Table_A. 

In my actual implementation the possible values in Table_A will be inserted into the database on initial load (just after installation) and can only every be Pass, Fail or Inconclusive with a similar constraint on b_Text.

Comment: @SimonJohnson "*Its got to be a string value*" - no it doesn't :) like I said you could use a surrogate key with a more approprite type as the PK and have the FK constraint on the unique column (not the PK). I will update my answer to show you what I mean. The approach your taking just now will most definitely cause you problems in the future.

Comment: What problems can this cause?

Comment: @SimonJohnson see update. There are also other concerns such as performance (depending on how big the values for `a_Text` will be). Do a bit of digging into the subject and you will see there are various reasons why you shouldn't do it. That's not to say you *can't* do, however, more often than not it causes more problems in the long run.

Comment: I can see the advantage of using this system however in this case both Table A and Table B will only every contain three records. The tables will actually be marked as read only after those three records are added just after installation on the users machine. They exist to make a formal connection that this field can only ever contain one of these (the specified values) in those tables.

The user can never add to these two tables or cause more choices through action to become relevant as this is a pretty closed system.

Comment: @SimonJohnson your justification seems fair enough. The only concern is if in the future you decide to change those table values in future versions of your application you will essentially lose backwards compatibility.